# TimescaleDB unexpected result with `time_bucket_gapfill` and `locf`

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, time-series, timescaledb

I have a dataset where I store count of users per day for certain portals in my platform.

Here the small example of data that I've

```
id     date        value

7057    2022-01-26  1   
7062    2022-01-31  13  
7063    2022-02-01  17  
7064    2022-02-02  20  
7065    2022-02-03  21  
7067    2022-02-05  23  
7069    2022-02-07  24  
7073    2022-02-11  25  
7074    2022-02-12  26  
7078    2022-02-16  30  
7079    2022-02-17  32  
7080    2022-02-18  33  
7084    2022-02-22  34  
7093    2022-03-03  35  
7098    2022-03-08  36  
7101    2022-03-11  37  
7126    2022-04-05  38  
7133    2022-04-12  39  
7144    2022-04-23  40  
7146    2022-04-25  41  
7149    2022-04-28  42  
7176    2022-05-25  43  
7177    2022-05-26  45  
7193    2022-06-11  46  
7203    2022-06-21  47  
7227    2022-07-15  48  
7237    2022-07-25  49  
10715   2022-08-22  48
```

Basically I want to have a chart that fills the missing dates and shows the previous available value.

For this purpose I've created this statement based on TimescaleDB docs.

```
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(
        '1 day',
        timestamp,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(1643155200),
        now()
    ) AS time,
    locf(sum(count)) as value
FROM portal_user_stats
WHERE portal = '6171a8601a00c437c4f219e0'
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time;
```

Simpley I fill the gaps of the missing dates and put last observed value. The important part is on the last 3 rows, where we have value `48` on `2022-07-15` then `49` on `2022-07-25` and again `48` on `2022-08-22`.

Hence I expect to see

```
2022-07-15 48 
2022-07-16 48 
... (value 48 till the 2022-07-24)
2022-07-24 48 
2022-07-25 49 
... (value 49 till the 2022-08-21)
2022-08-21 49 
2022-08-22 48 
... (value 48 till the current date)
2022-08-27 48  (current date)
```

However I got this result

```
2022-07-15 48
...
2022-07-23 48
2022-07-24 49 <- expected to be 48 and only on next line start 49
2022-07-25 49
...
2022-08-20 49
2022-08-21 49
2022-08-22 49 <- expected to be 48 starting from this value till the end
2022-08-23 49
2022-08-24 49
2022-08-25 49
2022-08-26 49
2022-08-27 49
```

I would like to know where is the mistake that it produces wrong result and how to achive desired result?

Comment: What is the first result? Is it Jan 26th or Jan 25th?

Comment: for some reason it's Jan 25th. I didn't get that part as well. The dates are shifted down by one day.

Comment: Have you tried (instead of *<= now()*) to put it to a midnight date? As far as I remember, the time buckets are calculated backwards.